# after generate build with flutter app craches and not open

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, apk

After generate build in release mode in android studio get these warnings

> ```
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> ```

```
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.6.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_ml_vision-0.9.3+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebasemlvision\FirebaseMlVisionPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.6+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\SharedPreferencesPlugin.java:25: warning: [deprecation] getFlutterEngine()
 in FlutterPluginBinding has been deprecated
    setupChannel(binding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), binding.getApplicationContext());
                        ^
1 warning
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

and generate APK using

```
flutter build apk --release
```

and install it successfully and when try to open app craches and not open
and here's the logs and warnings while generating build:

> 

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.6.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-6.0.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebasemessaging\FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_ml_vision-0.9.3+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebasemlvision\FirebaseMlVisionPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.6+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\SharedPreferencesPlugin.java:25: warning: [deprecation] getFlutterEngine()
 in FlutterPluginBinding has been deprecated
    setupChannel(binding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), binding.getApplicationContext());
                        ^
1 warning
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Comment: After installing the app, can you show the logs?

Comment: It runs well in debug mode but after generate apk and install it on a device it crashes.

Comment: You can run the app in release mode adding --release flag, so you can get the logs when the app crashes on release

Comment: ok, will try it and write logs in question if craches

Comment: it runs normal and not craching

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the warning was a [known issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106537) that is coming from Android itself and not on Flutter, as explained [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106537#issuecomment-1165558491):

> The warnings are coming from `android` itself. It shouldn't break your
> app, at least until those methods that are being called are removed
> from android itself. Keep in mind that just because the packages are
> the latest versions doesn't mean that they are up to date on the
> native side. For the foreseeable future, this shouldn't affect your
> app, but if it bothers you, file issues with the appropriate repo.
> Although, I imagine the plugin authors should be aware of this and
> will most likely be working on it. As this isn't actually an issue
> with `flutter`, I'll be closing.